# How do I transform an image when using Open GL Framebuffer in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, framebuffer

I'm using a live streaming library called Cine.io to save a frame from the stream to Android's external storage.

The library itself uses Google's Grafika resource.

When I simply set up a ByteBufferand then read it with GLReadPixel, the image is saved properly but it is inverted since GL images have the reverse coordinates of BMP coordinates.

In order to resolve this issue, I believe the most effective solution is to use an open GL framebuffer to render the incoming frame, flip it with an ortho matrix, and then read it with GLReadPixel in order to save it to disk.

This is the code that I believe will achieve this goal:

```
   int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);


    int[] fboId = new int[1];
    int[] rendId = new int[1];
    float[] projMatrix = new float[16];

    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fboId, 0);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId[0]);

         GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, rendId, 0);
    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, rendId[0]);
    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,GLES20.GL_RGBA4, width, height);


    switch(GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER)){
        case GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
            Log.i(TAG, "Is Complete");
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT:
            Log.i(TAG, "Incomplete Attachment");
            break;
        case GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT:
            Log.i(TAG, "Missing Attachment");
            break;
        default: Log.i(TAG, "Something else is going on");

    }
    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER,rendId[0] );
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId[0]);
    GLES20.glViewport(0,0,width, height);
    android.opengl.Matrix.orthoM(projMatrix, 0, 0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);


  GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height,
            GLES20.GL_RGBA4, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);




    GlUtil.checkGlError("glReadPixels");
    buf.rewind();
```

However the code simply generates a blank image file that is empty (size 3.6kb). In addition, the variable "buff"'s block consists of only 0's after the GLreadpixels method is called on it.

Finally, if I set BindFramebuffer to 0 (default bind) and place it prior to the GLReadPixels call, then the image does show up but still inverted - it's like the Framebuffer commands never interacted with it.

How can I solve this?

PS: a lot of folks are trying to answer a previous, more convoluted version of the question below - but the crux of it still holds.

Answer (score 0):

You could always flip the buffer manually. I haven't worked with java's `ByteBuffer` so the following code may not work, but it's mainly just supposed to be an example.

```
//num channels being the amount of channels per pixel, 4 representing r, g, b, a
int num_channels = 4;
//allocate buffer size
ByteBuffer new_buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * num_channels);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

//calculate row size of image
int row_size = width * num_channels
//loop through the contents of the buffer and flip it
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < row_size; ++x) {
        //put a row of bytes starting from the end of the buffer into the start of the new buffer
        new_buf.put(buf.get(((height - (y + 1)) - x) * row_size));
    }
}
```

However this is pretty slow and definitely not ideal in an update loop. Instead, in your render code you can change how the texture is projected onto the screen using a matrix. Try using `glOrtho` like so:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0f, window_width, window_height, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

This should flip your textures when rendering. Try experimenting and messing around with different values to get a feel for it.

Comment: Definitely went through the song and dance of the framebuffer so I could reach option #2. My issue if figuring out the matching methods in Android. I will.

Comment: I think the code you provided for option #2 is for GL v1.0. Since I'm using GL 2.0 in Android I'm having some trouble finding the matching code to bind a transformation to a framebuffer.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, I'm still pretty new to openGL but I think I can still try help. So, I'm a bit confused, you're reading the pixels from the default frame buffer (0) and saving them to the disk? Why do you need the frame buffer you created above it then? Shouldn't you be binding to the frame buffer id you created above?
What I would do is bind to the frame buffer you created above when rendering so that it gets rendered to the frame buffer (it won't display on the screen). When rendering you apply the matrix transformation, then, you can read the pixels from this frame buffer.

Comment: Could you also maybe show your render code so I can see what you're doing to try help? Thanks :)

Comment: just updated the question with new code. Hopefully folks can help - I've been on this for hours and still can't get it to work. By the way you were right that I was wrongly reading from the default frame buffer - which made me believe that the Framebuffer was rendering, when it fact it wasn't.

Comment: Definitely download [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com) so you can find out what is being rendered to your frame buffer. It's great for other things too, but I mostly use it to view all created textures so it's much easier to debug with. Also, thanks for posting more code, but I still think you're missing the vital render code in your post, can you maybe post that first? Your frame buffer code looks fine right now, I think the problem is the render code. By the way, you call `glFramebufferTexture2D` twice, it should only be called once after `glTexImage2D`, but this shouldn't make a difference

Comment: maybe the problem is I don't have render code... this is how new I am to open GL. I expect that once I've set the framebuffer it will capture the data from the ByteBuffer, like a filter before glReadPixels runs. Does the render code need to occur in between those two?

Comment: I also had added a renderbuffer (it's commented out for now) - I can add that as well but.. the result is the same. Framebuffer does register as complete either way. Maybe the gap here is that I need to draw over to the framebuffer, but before or after readpixels? And how? I think that's the part in the documentation I've bee n consulting that I'm confused about.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed you had render code because you said the image was being generated when you removed the frame buffer. Is anything showing up on your screen when you run the app? If there is, that means you are rendering something and are probably grabbing the screens pixels and saving them as a bitmap. What `glReadPixels` actually does is read the pixels from the frame buffer and puts it into the bytebuffer. I'm not sure how your bitmap is saved if nothing is rendered, unless you load the image contents into the bytebuffer and then save it?

Comment: You don't actually need a frame buffer if you already have the image bytebuffer contents as you can just flip it like I posted above and that'd be faster than rendering to a frame buffer and then reading it's pixels. Anyway, I'll try to come up with some example code tonight (11:20am here), but as for now I must be off.

Comment: OMG a week of my life on FrameBuffer. OK so when your refer to flipping the image are you referring to your option #1 (inverting the pixels) or option #2?  Let me add the basic code as it was when I found it (unconverted) in the question. The problem with it was that the result was a flipped Bitmap- what I needed to do was rotate the frame before copying to bitmap to account for coordinate diffs between BMP and openGL.

Comment: @guoxx  Swapbuffers gets called at a different part of the app, constantly, to update the view during live streaming. However when saveframe is called, the image is still in the ByteBuffer and successfully transfers to a bitmap (albeit upside down) when I remove the framebuffer. And within the saveframe method, swapbuffers does not get called at all before read pixel.

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long to fix this man, I don't think I'm very good at helping others, but I'm trying :p. So, I think this code should work [here](http://pastebin.com/cD5qUwcj). It should transform the bitmap pixels and flip it on the y axis, but I can't actually test it. If this doesn't work though, the solution shouldn't be too hard, just look up how to flip an android bitmap. :)

Comment: @QualityPixels Thanks for this. This was the method I'd been using (though you streamlined it by getting me to reuse the same variable). Also since you're dealing with OpenGL you have to rotate the image and scale it to mirror it - otherwise text appears inverted in the image. I'm not going to set this question as answered since I was really focused on using a Framebuffer - and we never resolved it. There go 5 nights out of my life! I really appreciate your help though!

Comment: That's alright. Again, sorry it took so long. For future reference, to do what you wanted to do with a frame buffer you had to have openGL render code that uses `glBegin`/`glEnd` or a vertex buffer object (VBO) along with `glDrawArrays`/`glDrawElements` (you could look up rendering tutorials online). A frame buffer is just used to render something off-screen. Anyway, good luck in the future.